# Received Image from socket and display in Qml

Tags: qt

I want to received image through using TCP socket and display in QMl window.

currently  :I am able to receive .png image from socket.  and : able to display the image from local disk in qml using image provider. but while integrating the both things i am facing the issue. how to call the socket's function.

````
    tcpserver.h
    class MyTcpServer : public QObject
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
    explicit MyTcpServer(QObject *parent = 0);
    signals:
    public slots:
        void newConnection();
        void on_readyRead();
     private:
        QTcpServer *server;
    };```
    ```
    tcpserver.cpp
    QByteArray array,array1;
    MyTcpServer::MyTcpServer(QObject *parent) :
        QObject(parent)
    {server = new QTcpServer(this);
        connect(server, SIGNAL(newConnection()),
                this, SLOT(newConnection()));
        connect(server,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(readyRead()));
         if(!server->listen(QHostAddress::Any, 9999))
        {
            qDebug() << "Server could not start";
        }
        else
        {
            qDebug() << "Server started!";
        }
    }
    
    void MyTcpServer::newConnection()
    {
        QTcpSocket *socket = server->nextPendingConnection();
        if(socket)
        {
        connect(socket ,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(on_readyRead()));
        socket->write("Hello client \r\n");
        socket->flush();
        socket->waitForBytesWritten(3000);
        }
    }
    void MyTcpServer::on_readyRead()
    {
        QTcpSocket * server = dynamic_cast<QTcpSocket*>(sender());
        qDebug()<<"reading..";
    
             if(server)
             {
              qDebug()<<"Array size " << array.size() ;
              array.append(server->readAll());
              if(array.size()<230400)
              {
                qDebug()<<"Array size " << array.size() ;
              }
    
              else {
                qDebug()<<"Array size else " << array.size() ;
                cv::Mat img,img1;
                cv::Size const frame_size(240,320);
                img = cv::Mat(240,320, CV_8UC3,array.data());
                qDebug()<<"Image type " <<img.type();
                qDebug()<<"Array size " << array.size() ;
                qDebug()<<"beforeImage size size " << img.dims;
                cv::imshow("image display",img);
                cv::waitKey(5000);
                QImage imdisplay((uchar*)img.data, img.cols, img.rows, img.step, QImage::Format_RGB888);
            }
        }
    }
    //socket->close()
    
    }
    
    ```
````

imageprovider.cpp

````
QImage QmlImageProvider::requestImage(const QString &id, QSize *size, const QSize &requestedSize)
{
    printf("In request function ..\n");
    MyTcpServer *m = new MyTcpServer();
    m->newConnection();
    printf("after connectrion....");
    QImage image1= m->on_readyRead();
    printf("after request....");
    return image;

}
```
````

Comment: Please attach integrating part of your code, and your issue.

Comment: Update the question and place it there

Comment: tcpserver.h ``` 
class MyTcpServer : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyTcpServer(QObject *parent = 0);


signals:

public slots:
    void newConnection();
    void on_readyRead();
 private:
    QTcpServer *server;
};

Comment: `"...i am facing the issue"`: what issue?

Comment: Error:: In static member function ‘static void qt_static_metacall(QObject*, QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)’: error: variable ‘QImage _r’ has initializer but incomplete type case 1: { QImage _r = _t->on_readyRead(); ^ : error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class QImage’ case 1: { QImage _r = _t->on_readyRead();

Comment: Do you have `#include <QImage>` in all files that use `QImage`?

Comment: yes I have included #include <QImage> in all files

Comment: is there any suggestion ?

Comment: @Farshid616 any comment on this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You should move MyTcpServer *m = new MyTcpServer(); to **ImageProvider** class constructor and **m** to class members, also create a **signal** in your MyTcpServer class and connect it to your ImageProvider updateImage slot.
P.S Maybe need to change updateImage from simple function to slot.

**tcpserver.h**

```
class MyTcpServer : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
explicit MyTcpServer(QObject *parent = 0);
signals:
    void newImageReceived(QImage);
.
.
.
```

**tcpserver.cpp on_readyRead()**

```
            cv::imshow("image display",img);
            cv::waitKey(5000);
            QImage imdisplay((uchar*)img.data, img.cols, img.rows, img.step, QImage::Format_RGB888);

            emit newImageReceived(imdisplay);
```

**qmlimageprovider.cpp**

```
QmlImageProvider::QmlImageProvider()
 : QQuickImageProvider(QQuickImageProvider::Image)
{
    m = new MyTcpServer();
    connect(m, &MyTcpServer::newImageReceived, this, &QmlImageProvider::updateImage);
    m->newConnection();
}
```

**qmlimageprovider.h**

```
class QmlImageProvider : public QQuickImageProvider
{
public:
    QmlImageProvider();
    QImage requestImage(const QString &id, QSize *size, const QSize &requestedSize) override;
public slots:
    void updateImage(QImage new_image);

private:
    QImage image;
    MyTcpServer *m;
};
```

Comment: error: ‘connect’ was not declared in this scope
      connect(m, &MyTcpServer::newImageReceived, this, &QmlImageProvider::updateImage);

Comment: I tried with  QObject::connect but it throwing error: no matching function for call to ‘QObject::connectImpl(const Object*&, void**, const Object*&, void**, QtPrivate::QSlotObject<void (QmlImageProvider::*)(QImage), QtPrivate::List<QImage>, void>*, Qt::ConnectionType&, const int*&, const QMetaObject*)’
         return connectImpl(sender, reinterpret_cast<void **>(&signal),

Comment: Read this answer carefully to get the idea of signal and slot https://stackoverflow.com/a/42714793/3365136

Comment: Yes Thanks Farshid16. i have update my qmlimageprovider.h file by class QmlImageProvider : public QQuickImageProvider, public MyTcpServer
{
public:
    QmlImageProvider();
    QImage requestImage(const QString &id, QSize *size, const QSize &requestedSize) override;
    void updateImage(QImage new_image);

public:
    QImage image; ```                                   is a right way ? because i am able to compile the code but while running facing new issue

Comment: No it's not correct, I've updated the answer.

Comment: In constructor ‘QmlImageProvider::QmlImageProvider()’:
qmlimageprovider.cpp:120:89: error: ‘connect’ was not declared in this scope
          connect(m, &MyTcpServer::newImageReceived, this, &QmlImageProvider::updateImage);
But still its showing me this error i am not getting

Comment: Your QmlImageProvider class should inherit QObject so add it to your class

Comment: yes its working but after clicking on click to show nothing is shown

Comment: qrc:/main.qml:49:9: QML Image: Cannot anchor to an item that isn't a parent or sibling.
qrc:/main.qml:21:5: QML Connections: Cannot assign to non-existent property "onNewFrameReceived"
qrc:/main.qml:22: ReferenceError: imageprovider is not defined
In request function ..
qrc:/main.qml:49:9: QML Image: Failed to get image from provider: image://imageprovider/cover
reading..
Array size  0
Array size  65536
reading..
Array size  65536
Array size  131072
reading..
Array size  131072
Array size  196608
reading..
Array size  196608
Array size else  230400
Array size  230400

Comment: It mns we can receive the complete image size through socket but not getting Image

Comment: I am not getting any image but i can receive the complete size of image