# How to launch Mainwindow from a dialog in Qt

Tags: windows, qt

I want to open Mainwindow of my application from a dialog. Actually I want to first launch a small dialog window then after pressing ok button on dialog, the MainWindow should open. My approach right now is like below but it's not working.

On Mainwindow load the below lines are there

```
Dialog diag;
diag.setModal(true);
diag.exec()
```

And on click event of OK button of dialog I had put the below lines:

```
Mainwindow mainw;
mainw.show()
```

Please suggest how to do it correctly so that Mainwindow is opened from click of ok button on dialog which appears first.

The complete code is as below
below is my complete code as suggested by @Farshid616

**Mainwindow.ccp**

```
    MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
        QMainWindow(parent),
        ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
    {
    
           
        Dialog *dialog=new Dialog();
    
        ui->setupUi(this);
    
      

QObject::connect(dialog,&Dialog::accepted,this,&MainWindow::onAccept);
    
    
    }
    
    MainWindow::~MainWindow()
    {
        delete ui;
    }


void MainWindow::onAccept()
{
    this->show();
}
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
private slots:     
    void onAccept();
```

**dialog.h**

```
signals:
    void accepted();
```

**dialog.cpp**

```
 #include "dialog.h"
    #include "ui_dialog.h"
    
    Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
        QDialog(parent),
        ui(new Ui::Dialog)
    {
        ui->setupUi(this);
    }
    
    Dialog::~Dialog()
    {
        delete ui;
    }
    
    void Dialog::on_buttonBox_accepted()
    {
        emit accepted();
        this->accept();
    }
```

The mainwindow.ui has no widgets and dialog.ui has buttonBox with Ok and Cancel buttons.

Answer (score 2):

You should create a signal in your dialog class, and connect that signal on your MainWindow class to a slot and show your MainWindow on that slot.

**MainWindow.cpp**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent): QMainWindow(parent)
, ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{

    ui->setupUi(this);

    Dialog *dialog=new Dialog();
    QObject::connect(dialog,&Dialog::accepted,this,&MainWindow::onAccept);
    dialog->show();
}

void MainWindow::onAccept()
{
    this->show();
}
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
private slots:
    void onAccept();
```

**dialog.h**

```
signals:
    void accepted();
```

**dialog.cpp**

```
void Dialog::on_buttonBox_accepted()
{
    emit accepted();
    this->accept();
}
```

And don't forget to remove **w.show();** line on your main.cpp file.

Comment: How to create a signal in the dialog class please share the code

Comment: I've updated the answer check it out. Also read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42714173/example-slot-signal-between-two-object-qt/42714793#42714793

Comment: i tried to implement you suggested code. It gives error no matching call to connect(.....). I had defined dialog as instance of Dialog.Please suggest the solun.

Comment: You should write the connect in MainWindow constructor

Comment: i have edited my original post with the code suggested by you. It runs but Mainwindow is opened first not dialog. Request you comment please.

Comment: Add dialog.show(); to MainWindow constructor and remove w.show(); from main.cpp. Check my answer again, I've update it.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a `MainWindow` object outside of the function scope, or else it will be destroyed when the function has finished.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>
#include <QDialog>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QDialog dialog;
    QPushButton *accept_button = new QPushButton{"Accept"};
    QObject::connect(accept_button, &QPushButton::clicked, &dialog, &QDialog::accept);
    QPushButton *reject_button = new QPushButton{"Reject"};
    QObject::connect(reject_button, &QPushButton::clicked, &dialog, &QDialog::reject);
    QVBoxLayout *dialog_layout = new QVBoxLayout{&dialog};
    dialog_layout->addWidget(new QLabel{"Open mainwindow?"});
    dialog_layout->addWidget(accept_button);
    dialog_layout->addWidget(reject_button);

    MainWindow w;
    if (dialog.exec() == QDialog::Accepted)
    {
        qDebug() << "Accepted";
        w.show();
    }
    else
        qDebug() << "Rejected";

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have recently implented the same architecture in my app. here's how I'm doing it. I'm using Pyside2, you can translate my code to C++.

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow,  Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self, file_name,parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        """
        __init__ code lines
        """


class HomeDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, home_dialog.Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(HomeDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.openFile.clicked.connect(self.get_file_name)

    def get_file_name(self):
        file_name = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open config file',
                                                            dir=path.join("/"),
                                                            filter="xml (*.xml)")
        if not file_name[0]:
            return None
        else:
            self.path = file_name
            self.accept()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle(ProxyStyle())
    d = HomeDialog()
    if d.exec_():
        mainWin = MainWindow(file_name=d.path)
        mainWin.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```